# Какой элемент управления использовать для редактора кода с подсветкой синтаксиса и контекстным меню?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, uwp

Для написания импровизированной IDE для Паскаля ищу элемент управления:

1. Позволяющий отображать текст в 10^6 символов, и не тормозить при прокрутке.
2. Позволяющий менять цвет шрифта и ещё какой-либо атрибут (цвет фона, полужирность) для произвольных диапазонов символов.
3. Иметь возможность в обработчике событий нажатия кнопок мыши и клавиш клавиатуры, определить над каким символом это произошло. Это для вывода соответствующего элементу кода контекстного меню.

Пока остановился на RichTextBox в WPF, но не ясно как быть с третьим пунктом.

Comment: Возьмите готовый компонент: [Fast Colored TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) или [Scintilla](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, Scintilla отличный вариант. Получился хороший редактор кода. Правда, встроенный лексический анализатор Паскаля, вскоре перестал удовлетворять и его пришлось переписать на свой, но опять же Scintilla дал всё, чтобы подсвечивать код по результатам анализа. Спасибо @Alexander Petrov.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать AvalonEdit
http://avalonedit.net/

`Install-Package AvalonEdit -Version 5.0.4`

или

`dotnet add package AvalonEdit --version 5.0.4`

WPF:

```
<avalonEdit:TextEditor
    xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
    Name="textEditor"
    SyntaxHighlighting="Pascal"
    FontFamily="Consolas"
    FontSize="10pt"/>
```

P.S. Как я понял встроенной поддержки синтаксиса паскаля тут нет. Если заинтересовало именно это решение, есть возможность написать свой:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/XSHD-Tags

Тогда надо будет подключать так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057464/10502674